# при запуске напрямую скрипт работает, а в кроне—нет

Tags: python, cron

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, os.path
import random

DIR = '/home/woolf/Workspace/background/images'

count_wallpaper = (len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR)]))

if os.listdir(DIR):
    random_image = random.randint(1,count_wallpaper)
    os.system("/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri " + DIR + "/" + str(random_image) + ".jpg")
else:
    print "Not found files in " + str(DIR)
```

Есть такой простой код на питоне и если запустить просто как ./backgrond.py то всё работате,а если через крон, то нет.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/woolf/Workspace/background/background.py
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Setting background with Python2.7 Crontab in Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12707411/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "если запустить просто как ./backgrond.py" - запущен от Вашего имени.
2. "если через крон" - от имени пользователя cron

Соответственно, чей фон должен менять этот скрипт ?

Comment: а... разве он не указал себя?

Comment: Нет. os.system("/...

Comment: woolf@woolf:~$ crontab -u woolf -l
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/woolf/Workspace/background/background.py

Comment: как видно я вывел кронтаб для пользователя woolf

Comment: `crontab -e` -> `* * * * * /usr/bin/whoami >>/tmp/whoami.cron` затем `tail -F /tmp/whoami.cron` показывает, что cron запускает от текущего пользователя, который `crontab -e` вызывал, а не `cron` пользователя. Ответ же есть по ссылке, которую я под вопросом привёл.